# Windows Azure Services status from code

Tags: c#, api, rest, azure

I'm working on a application which will need to know the status of Window Azure services, **not my applications**(i.e.: SQL Databases, Storage, Access Control 2.0, etc).

I'm aware that Windows azure has a REST API, but I didn't found anything about services health or status.

Comment: When you say `status of Windows Azure services`, what do you mean? Do you mean the status of your applications deployed in Azure or do you mean the status of Azure Services like Storage etc.?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Status of Azure Services.
Something like this: https://www.windowsazurestatus.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found out with fiddler, that this site: https://www.windowsazurestatus.com/ is using these two api functions:

/odata/ServiceCurrentIncidents?api-version=1.0 (for current status)

/odata/ServiceHistoricalIncidents?endDate=&api-version=1.0 (historical data)

I've also learned that the calls to these functions are made from javascript. In this case, I assume that these are publicly available APIs without documentation.

Comment: It just stop working, do you have some alternative source for the status?

Answer (score 0):

Following document might help you. It gives status of service on https://management.core.windows.net//services/hostedservices/

msdn document link :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460806.aspx

Thanks,
Gaurav

Answer (score 0):

As of now there are no public APIs available which will give you the status of Azure services like what you see on windowsazurestatus.com. One thing I noticed on that site is that it provides RSS feeds for service status. One possibility for you would be to build an application which consumes these RSS feeds.

Comment: RSS could be an option. But all are empty right now, and I don't know what data will be present in case of problems with the services.

Comment: I played with it last night. Whenever there's an issue, you will get some data back. For example, Azure had some issues with Visual Studio Online yesterday and I saw data coming in. I guess you would need to wait for a service to degrade to test it yourself :)